# Unable to click on hidden checkbox (Selenium-Webdriver)

Tags: css, ruby, selenium

I have an issue I cannot resolve by myself.

There's a web page with a check box on it.  See scr1.png attached.
The check box is some sort of a decoration ( I don't know what this technology is).  I cannot click on it, and Webdriver doesn't see it. Real check box is hidden. It is hidden in CSS file (see right corner of a scr1.png)

Now when I change it manually in FireBug from `visibility: none` to `visibility: yes`, then real check box is shown on the page (see screen shot 2).

#### ISSUE

[image: Screen 1]
[image: Screen 2]

I'm trying to click on this check box like this:

```
@driver.find_element(:id,"MainContent_chkAuthorize").click
```

But then I'm getting `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError:` because element is hidden and cannot be found by Webdriver.

1. Is there any way to overcome this issue?
2. How can I change the visibility with Webdriver?
3. How can I click this element at last?

Comment: webdriver doesn't like to interact with elements that are not visible

Comment: Can you click the checkbox manually?

Comment: I'm trying to write automation script. No problem to click on it manually

Comment: this is obvious that it's not interacting with hidden element, however I'm trying to figure out how to overcome this? maybe there's a way how to make this check box visible

Comment: if you want to forcefully click hidden elements, then you can try making use of Javascript Execution

Answer (score 0):

To make checkbox visible you should change its [`display`](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/) property.

```
input.styled{
  display:block;  // Or you can remove this
}
```

Comment: Sounds good, but how to automate it using Selenium-Webdriver + Ruby ?